# How to implement Insert, Update and Delete in a parent class that works for all database models using sqlite-net?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I'm using a `SQLite` database in a `Windows 8 Store Application`.
Furthermore I use the SQLite wrapper `sqlite-net` to do operations on the database.

I will explain this in detail so that you understand my situation.
There are `Model classes` that contain the business logic, for example the class **Location**. Then there are `DatabaseModels` from which the Database Tables are generated, for example **LocationDb**.

I don't want to implement the basic database methods like **Insert(Model model), Update(Model model)**, **Delete(int id)**, **GetAllRecords()** and **GetRecord(int id)** in every Model class. Instead I want to implement these methods in a base class of all models. This base class of all models is called **ModelBase**; the base class of all database Models is **DbModelBase**.

There is no problem implementing the Insert method as follows for all models:

```
    public int Insert(ModelBase model)
    {
        int id;
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(MainApplication.DBPath))
        {
            db.Insert(model.GetDbModelFromModel());
            id = (int)SQLite3.LastInsertRowid(db.Handle);
        }
        return id;
    }
```

But I don't know how to implement the other ones using sqlite-net.
I need to find a specific data record in a specific table. I have a model object which contains the id. **But how to make one method work with all model classes without explicitly calling the specific table?**
The following code works for a single specific database table...

```
        using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(MainApplication.DBPath))
        {
            var queryResult = db.Table<LocationDb>().Where(l => l.Id == model.Id);
            if (queryResult.Count() == 1)
            {
                db.Update(new TeacherDb(model));
            }
        }
```

... but I can not write

```
var queryResult = db.Table<typeof(databaseModel)>().Where(t => t.Id == model.Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a [generic function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```
public class BaseModel<T> where T : Type
{
    protected T Id;
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a new record to data base. It doesn't check for record existance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected BaseModel<T> Add() 
    {
        try
        {
            var entities = Variable.CurrentEntities;
            var dbSet = entities.Set<BaseModel<T>>();
            var result = dbSet.Add(this);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogException.HandleException(exception);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected bool Update()
    {
        try
        {
            var entities = Variable.CurrentEntities;
            var dbSet = entities.Set<BaseModel<T>>();
            var original = dbSet.Find(this);
            entities.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(this);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogException.HandleException(exception);
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected BaseModel<T> Delete()
    {
        try
        {
            var entities = Variable.CurrentEntities;
            var dbSet = entities.Set<BaseModel<T>>();
            var result = dbSet.Remove(this);
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogException.HandleException(exception);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected bool Upsert()
    {
        try
        {
            var entities = Variable.CurrentEntities;
            var dbSet = entities.Set<BaseModel<T>>();
            dbSet.AddOrUpdate(this);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogException.HandleException(exception);
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected BaseModel<T> Save()
    {
        try
        {
            var entities = Variable.CurrentEntities;
            var dbSet = entities.Set<BaseModel<T>>();
            var original = dbSet.Find(Id);
            if (original == null)
            {
                original = dbSet.Add(this);
            }
            else
            {
                entities.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(this);
            }
            entities.SaveChanges();
            return original;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            LogException.HandleException(exception);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```